# Error in getting the <a href = ' '> value

Tags: php, mysql, anchor

I am trying to get the value of an anchor tag using PHP code. When I click the hyperlink, however, I am not getting the value.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
    $gettingevents = "SELECT event_name FROM events";
    $resultgettingevents = mysqli_query($con,$gettingevents) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    while($getevents = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultgettingevents)){
        $gettablenames = $getevents['event_name'];
        echo '<a id="events" href="registeredevents.php?tablename='.$getevents['event_name'].'">'.$gettablenames.'</a>';

        if(isset($_GET['tablename'])){
            $clickedtable =$_GET['tablename'];
            echo "the clicked table is ".$clickedtable;
        }else{
            echo "";
        }

    }
?>
```

I am getting the following error:

> undefined index: tablename in

What is wrong with my code? How can I get the hyperlink value?

Comment: why you used `$clickedtable =$_GET['tablename']` this line at the end of while loop?

Comment: ermmm to get the hyperlink value...

Comment: you also need to remove the space in `registeredevents.php?tablename =` - besides putting the GET array first and checking if it's set/not empty

Comment: you should wrap `$clickedtable = $_GET['tablename'];` in `if(isset[$_GET['tablename']) { }`, and I suppose it should live outside the while loop, right?

Comment: @Jeff i tried your method.i am not getting the values

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry.. i am not quite understand your point...say me once again in detail..i  removed white space in the link..

Comment: `registeredevents.php?tablename =` the space in there counts as a character, it needs to read as `registeredevents.php?tablename=` along with what I said to use a conditional statement.

Comment: plus, that's also open to an SQL injection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: okay i got your point...i changed my code..but still it doesn't get the names..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
    $gettingevents = "SELECT event_name FROM events";
    $resultgettingevents = mysqli_query($con,$gettingevents) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while($getevents = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultgettingevents)){
        $gettablenames = $getevents['event_name'];
        echo '<a id="events" href="registeredevents.php?tablename='.$getevents['event_name'].'">'.$gettablenames.'</a>';
        if(isset($_GET['tablename'])){    
          $clickedtable =$_GET['tablename'];
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: the `if ` will be executed when you actually visit on of those generated urls,for the first time you are visiting the `url = registeredevents.php`.But when you click on the url whcih is genarated then your url will look like `url = registeredevents.php?tablename=xyz`. Then the `$clickedtable = xyz`

Comment: i clicked the link and i echoed **$clickedtable** it is not printing..it's not entering into if loop.....

Comment: can you add the url as an example which comes after clicking on generated url

Comment: please check my code just now i edited  my post...my url link is `'<a id="events" href="registeredevents.php?tablename='.$getevents['event_name'].'">'.$gettablenames.'</a>'`

Comment: please share URL from address bar after clicking on one of those generated URL. The code seems correct we have to debug from the URL from address bar

Comment: [link](http://localhost/Examples/Surya/registeredevents.php?tablename%20=Activity%20Based%20Events)

Comment: Yes copy that url and paste here i want to have a look

Comment: http://localhost/Examples/Surya/registeredevents.php?tablename%20=Activity%20Based%20Events

Comment: You still have that space between `tablename` and `=`! Thats the problem.

Comment: Or please for god sake copy your code only and paste. It will work